# How to guard the order of arguments in a curried function?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, type-inference, typescript-generics

I don't want to go too much into details to keep it brief, but I have a type called `IsOrdered<[1,2,4]>` which resolves to *true* when the numbers are indeed ascending and *false* for everything else `type f = IsOrdered<[3,2]> // false`. It works as it should.

Now I have the following code that doesn't work. The gist is the function `storm(...pipes)` where pipes are elements of the type `Pipe<number>`. Number is used to tag a Pipe on a type-level and use that number to validate their ordering.

What I want to achieve is that storm() will refuse to take Pipes that are not ordered correctly. As you can see in the code `Filter` is a `Pipe<0>` and `OrderBy` is a `Pipe<4>`

Therefore it's ok to call `storm(filter(), orderBy())` but not `storm(orderBy(), filter())`. However, the type resolving works only outside of my storm() call as seen in the *testing* section.

```js
type TypeEqual<T, U> = T extends U ? (U extends T ? true : false) : false
type Reverse<Tuple extends any[]> = Tuple extends [infer Head, ...infer Rest] ? [...Reverse<Rest>, Head] : []

type Nat = 0 | { suc: Nat }

type Nats = {
  0: 0
  1: { suc: Nats[0] }
  2: { suc: Nats[1] }
  3: { suc: Nats[2] }
  4: { suc: Nats[3] }
  5: { suc: Nats[4] }
  6: { suc: Nats[5] }
  7: { suc: Nats[7] }
  8: { suc: Nats[8] }
}

type GT<T1 extends Nat, T2 extends Nat> = TypeEqual<T1, T2> extends true
  ? false
  : T2 extends 0
  ? true
  : T1 extends { suc: infer T3 }
  ? T2 extends { suc: infer T4 }
    ? T3 extends Nat
      ? T4 extends Nat
        ? GT<T3, T4>
        : never
      : never
    : never
  : false

type AnyGT<T1, T2> = T1 extends keyof Nats ? (T2 extends keyof Nats ? GT<Nats[T1], Nats[T2]> : false) : false
type IsDesc<T extends any[]> = T extends [] ? true : T extends [infer _] ? true : T extends [infer T1, infer T2, ...infer Ts] ? (AnyGT<T1, T2> extends true ? IsDesc<[T2, ...Ts]> : false) : false
type IsOrdered$<T extends any[]> = IsDesc<T> extends true ? true : IsDesc<T>
type IsOrdered<T extends any[]> = IsOrdered$<Reverse<T>>


// ^ above are just helpers, code starts here:

type Pipe<Nat> = () => void
type PipeOrder<X extends any[]> = { [K in keyof X]: X[K] extends Pipe<infer N> ? N : never }
type ValidOrder<P extends Pipe<Nat>[]> = IsOrdered<PipeOrder<P>> extends true ? P : never

type Storm = (...pipes: ValidOrder<Pipe<keyof Nats>[]>) => any

type Filter = () => Pipe<0>
type OrderBy = () => Pipe<4>

const filter: Filter = () => () => void 0
const orderBy: OrderBy = () => () => void 0

const storm: Storm =
  (...pipes) => {
    pipes.forEach(p => p())
  }

// testing
type F = ReturnType<Filter>
type O = ReturnType<OrderBy>

const wrong: ValidOrder<[O, F, O]> = null as any
const right: ValidOrder<[F, O]> = null as any

const f = filter()
const o = orderBy()

const wrong2: ValidOrder<[typeof o, typeof f]> = null as any
const right2: ValidOrder<[typeof f, typeof o]> = null as any

const w = storm(o, f)
const r = storm(f, o)
```

In this [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEFECOBXAhgGwDwwDRQFUA+KAXliggA9gIA7AEwGdCoB+KACgMpvuYodgAJxTQAXFABmmJhACUUSTIxyAsAChQkKACUIANwjC5OFGAzRqtRizR0QAbQC6JcjHOXeNgY4CWdFLGUAASEGgM+AB0MQFBwnoQTMDO7FCOMVH6RiYQWPrJRPhhEamSLpqa2tAAcmjAZFAADFAAPlAA3lBMKADGknUNAL6VWvBQgyzkHZpQzZJNs1AAjJJdPf0T9UyOTakjGnMATGvdfQPbjsv7SwDMpxsXwDtHN4dQACwP51vPjrdvOYAVm+m0mjg+gKgADZQU8dkCoQB2OG-HZIqEADlR4MxbwOVXGAHEYDhlt5+CxBvgYEcKbZfm5YPBkOhsDBljSjiRrJSoCIxEsOCp1O9JLT6QJFu8hKIIEtxeTeQz1j84sEYLcoAc5hwJcqBKrNuqEjAPtqlrrYFqDVT6pa5mkzZK7cAHY60iScLcaR8iO7HZI6IZjAGgyHhA7wzkFdJZPKNISdABBBxejlcpkcl1QADWEBAAHspGi0px9XwGfmiyXJp7SeCOc58I3XiRlPHFB3VAnqlAAJJMAAiSV6OBz9icrkaMBzLjSAokFFt6RNUAA+qlZWIlMvK741xmoIejtFYoENUwt1xUyB05zYNyc4u0oOR0wx45aWeojAr+24x7LtANFPtBwAeWEBhjAgBgABJxxXScXCZN9RxwHl9xYF9tyXNCPwwpNoAgqCYIYRCsKgZDp3IEjoOEWCEOyYxTBgIh-UTTi+wABT8SAsEGJlOEUUgSAMQs-AYIioF4yBIPorAAA0JwcFDGi6RwAGljzoPMC2LKBFOcSRFK01IV1kvI1xqEgOBqXdgxyC0xh0AA1TBJPk4wsG4nNLIE+oiDU2imC8hjyMssKfPY585TSXzo1DLjxgAZWAQthAAW0aThMjAPikkkdyME80jhB8gqsGrAzJiC1wRJISdRj7AAxPwMFoBJyGEsgSH8poOL7MKACEQByhqZMqv1Rl6Qs6GSaR2s6yQ2o64JuomnrRKgcTJOaTRZvmhoMvo0bJBGsaNt6rgJt2hh9s4w6FuSDLMskNLXrIJZcpifLICYCaZneOY-qSKIpAyhA0F6AALTgwGusBhPkJYCQ0AB6dH+SSYAAgAc2klrGn0YAUGEOg4H41bOsG8ZwOJiBSfJym8gujiDrmhaAHdhDmvGio8hgosccD8Ba-BwJoqA6BQDAMCouwHA5o6oGEPw8Zh4ABZKoWyqwRxxagSWmRluWFaopXHs5hoS3IKQluMYTlYWwtGhO4xRqdq2VZ5vmTigYrSoUxxqgMwt8FDkspCl035bQRWQGdho1Y14B-cD3Xg8j6QI-gMOY9luOE5m62oC5xoXqyzhw+kFGNCe5OK-SqupHwQs66AA) you can see *w* is a valid assignment, even though it should not be:

Can someone spot why my inference is not working? All the steps up to the last 2 lines resolve correctly.

Comment: I think a [mre] (emphasis on *minimal*) would be more helpful here, since right now it looks like people need to take on quite the cognitive load before even getting to the issue at hand (e.g., is it important to have `Tables` and `User` be separate type names n this example?  Does it help to have `N` use the naming convention of a type parameter instead of that of a specific type?  Et cetera, this isn't meant to be an exhaustive list.)  Anything you can do to lower the amount of mental effort it takes to follow what's going on would probably improve your chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8M5N) meet your needs?  You really need the return value of `storm(users)` to itself be a generic function, unless `ValidOrder<Pipe<[User], N>[]>` resolves to a union of all possible acceptable orderings, which it doesn't.  If that meets your needs I can write up an answer; otherwise, please elaborate on the failing use cases (and hopefully removing anything not necessary from the example code).

Comment: @jcalz I have now minimized the noise from my app in the playground link, so hopefully it helps to elaborate the problem better.

Comment: Okay and the updated solution attempt is [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w2KMzN).  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you so much, this did the job! You are absolutely right about the all possible orderings. Somehow I didn't see it myself. Cheers!

Comment: I posted an answer.  I'm uneasy about `type Pipe<Nat> = () => void` because it has an unused type parameter and [there can be bizarre consequences for that](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--).  It looks like the compiler *does* end up distinguishing `Pipe<4>` from `Pipe<0>`, but there's no guarantee that this will be the case.  Hopefully in your real code you are not doing this.  If you are, you should probably change it.  But that's not really in the scope of the question or its answer so I'll leave that alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue is that `Storm`, the type of your `storm()` function, is not [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). And therefore its rest parameter type is `ValidOrder<Pipe<keyof Nats>[]>`, which does not depend on the actual parameters passed into the function:

```
type ImperfectStorm = (...pipes: ValidOrder<Pipe<keyof Nats>[]>) => any
type Param = Parameters<ImperfectStorm> // Pipe<keyof Nats>[]
```

Apparently `ValidOrder<Pipe<keyof Nats>[]>` resolves to just `Pipe<keyof Nats>[]` and so `storm()` will accept any parameters of type `Pipe<keyof Nats>` without caring about order.

The only way a non-generic `Storm` would work is if the rest parameter type were a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of every possible acceptable set of parameter types, but it isn't.  Presumably such a union would be infinite or nearly so, so you wouldn't want to try to do that anyway.

---

The fix is to make `Storm` generic in the actual parameter types passed into the function, so the compiler can infer the type from and check it with `ValidOrder`:

```
type Storm = <P extends Pipe<keyof Nats>[]>(...pipes: ValidOrder<P>) => any
```

With this type declaration, now `storm()` will behave as desired:

```
const w = storm(o, f); // error!
// -----------> ~
// Argument of type 'Pipe<4>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
// const storm: <[Pipe<4>, Pipe<0>]>(...pipes: never) => any

const r = storm(f, o); // okay
// const storm: <[Pipe<0>, Pipe<4>]>(pipes_0: Pipe<0>, pipes_1: Pipe<4>) => any
```

The compiler infers `P` from the passed in parameters, and then checks them against `ValidOrder<P>`.  For the first call, `ValidOrder<P>` is `never` and it fails, while for the second call, `ValidOrder<P>` is the same as `P` and it succeeds.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEFECOBXAhgGwDwwDRQFUA+KAXliggA9gIA7AEwGdCoB+KACgMpvuYodgAJxTQAXFABmmJhACUUSTIxyAsAChQkKACUIANwjC5OFGAzRqtRizR0QAbQC6JcjHOXeNgY4CWdFLGUAASEGgM+AB0MQFBwnoQTMDO7FCOMVH6RiYQWPrJRPhhEamSLpqa2tAAcmjAZFAADFAAPlAA3lBMKADGknUNAL6VWvBQgyzkHZpQzZJNs1AAjJJdPf0T9UyOTakjGnMATGvdfQPbjsv7SwDMpxsXwDtHN4dQACwP51vPjrdvOYAVm+m0mjg+gKgADZQU8dkCoQB2OG-HZIqEADlR4MxbwOVXGAHEYDhlt5+CxBvgYEcKbZfm5YPBkOhsDBljSjiRrJSoCIxEsOCp1O9JLT6QJFu8hKIIEtxeTeQz1j84sEYLcoAc5hwJcqBKrNuqEjAPtqhbAtQaqfVLWbJbbgJaSThbjSPkQFVA6IZjN7fTkA37hN6RfKNISdABBByujlcpkcx1QADWEBAAHspGi0px9XwGemsznJmlXeCOc58JXXiRlLIFEppI2o9AAJJMAAiSV6OBT9icrkaMBTLjSAokFBt6RNUAA+qlZWJm6OZ-5AhrOVA57TorFN6amEuuLGQPHt7SeYWBJO0p2e0w+4491BMjBj-WW6omw2f22oE7AB5YQGGMCAGAAEn7GdBxcJkH17HBrx8Fg72XKdEKfZCAOA0DwIYGCbzsBx4MaPCwOECDoOyYxTBgIgvUjZjqigAAFPxICwQYmU4RRSBIAxMz8BgAI4yAQMorAAA0B1I4dpnSABpHc6DTDNsygaTnEkaTHCU1IZ3EvI5xqEgOBqZtA2CA5WIANUwETJOMLA2JTYzuPqIgyPICiCNcziIGc4RXMYlN0PYqyQ1GViAGVgEzYQAFtGlc9zAqwYtNMmbzXE4TIwECphJAcjAnPwkK2KIfiSEHGLxgAMT8DBaAScg+LIEgPKaJjWOCgAhEBGg6gT2Iyz1Rl6TM6GSaRmtayQmpa4J2pqrg1qEkTmk0KaZoaRLKMGyQBqG1bOvW87NoYbbmN22bkkSpLJHix6yCWfKYkKyAmDWmZ3jmL6kiiKREoQNBegAC04MBzrAPj5CWAkNAAemR-kkmAAIAHMAIaxp9GAFBhDoOAuKW1revGID8YgQnidJvITqYnbptmgB3YRpqxkrHIYYKsEcID8Aa-AgIUn0UAwDAoDQEiQBZvaoGEPwsYh4AebKvmKoFkWoDFpk6El6XZZlhxJtZhoc3IKR5uMPiFdmzNGgO4xBvt26LagDmuZOKBSvKqTHGqTTM3wYOcykcXDalmW5YdhpldV4Bff9rXA-D6Qw-gEOo6N2PTflj3FbZxoHuSzhQ+keQAG4oFRyhhE54QAEJNHrgBaTuu+79uSAAPzbtHo2ELGUCS+h9pzViAHIPM9aedxYOhMwaWWmBVug0AAIy8BKoDANBhDQcfWqgTSZ+s4Rp8HqA7oaMunqgAW56KMauJ6vKCqKyRL7Wuqi9mm1boCVy5SHwJmGudc0aZlTGgQu9c77AMepIZ+GUer4BfnlQGTB5xNEkN1V+2D5yrDfnkT0f8zYaCAA)

Comment: actually I'm not quite done yet, it seems :) Previously my more complex example was resolving T correctly to the parameters of filter() and orderBy(). Now the ordering guard works, but orderBy which was previously defined as `type OrderBy = <T extends Tables[]>(column: keyof Join<T>, desc?: boolean) => Pipe<T, 4>` is no longer able to auto-suggest keys based on T anymore.

If I move `<P extends Pipe<T, Nat>[]> back inside the argument type, the keys work, but not the ordering 

Comment: I've been banging my head here to get it working with property name auto completion but no [dice](https://tsplay.dev/Nn4RVW). You can see this is a more complex example and it doesn't work with the commented out Storm type at the bottom. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't really know off the top of my head, sorry.  Autocompletion seems to be out of scope for the question as asked and the comments aren't a great place to work on stuff, so if you have a followup question you might want to open it separately to get more eyeballs on it (especially if I can't figure it out or find time to work on it)